Getting the ipv4 address of my VM
I just installed metasploit2 on VMware and changed its network to a Bridge Adapter. Now I want to get my Metasploit2 IPv4 but when I run ifconfig it shows only IPv6 for eth0. I need IPv4. What should I do to get my IP?
